# No PHP modules after compiling Apache

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, configuration, php

I'm trying to install Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6 on CentOS which I've done correctly and confirmed using `./apachectl configtest` and `php -v`. The problem is that Apache is not recognizing PHP scripts because the Apache install did not include any of the PHP modules that Apache requires.

The only thing the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.processing) tells me to do is to add the modules to `httpd.conf` by adding:

```
# Extra Modules
AddModule mod_php.c
AddModule mod_perl.c

# Extra Modules
LoadModule php_module         modules/mod_php.so
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
LoadModule perl_module        modules/libperl.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

which, when trying to start the server, outputs:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 156 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_php.so into server: /usr/
local/apache2/modules/mod_php.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've compiled both Apache and PHP correctly without any errors.

I compiled with this for Apache:

```
./configure --with-included-apr=/usr
make
make install
```

And this for PHP:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You (probably) need to use `--enable-so` in the apache configure params and definitely need to use `--with-apxs2=/path/to/apache` on the PHP configure.  See the [INSTALL file in the PHP source tree](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/INSTALL), it suggests these two options in the *Apache 2.x on Unix systems* section.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! You should definitely post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not leave it unanswered.

Apache cannot build `mod_php.so` as part of its build because it does not know how to parse or run PHP.  On the other hand PHP needs to know how Apache has been compiled to produce `mod_php.so`.  You need to specify:

- `--enable-so` to the configure script of Apache, to allow for building of extra modules as shared libraries.  And create `apxs`, the extension tool to build the shared libraries.
- And `--with-apxs2=/path/to/apache` to the configure script of PHP, for it to be able to build against Apache headers, find `apxs`, and generate `mod_php.so`.

Typically on a *nix system the Apache `--prefix` will default to `/usr/local` and `apxs` will end at `/usr/local/bin/apxs`.  Therefore the compilation should run as follows.

First Aapche (`httpd`) with:

```
./configure --enable-so
make
make install
```

And then PHP with:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
make
make install
```

References:

- [PHP INSTALL file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/INSTALL)